# Cloudfondry Eclipse plugin add existent app

Tags: eclipse-plugin, cloud-foundry

I have an existent deployed spring app up on cloudfoundry, deployed from one PC. Now I set up Eclipse with my project on another PC and I added my existent cloudfoundry deployment via the Cloudfoundry Eclipse plugin. The problem is that the CF Server with my deployed app is not sync-ed with my local eclipse project, so I cannot deploy any changes from my project.

Is there any way of doing this sync after I add my Cloudfoundry Server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The cloudfoundry deployment approach will not automatically (dynamically) maintain synchronization between your two eclipse environments. You might use a source control approach where you push your version from one eclipse environment to github and use that as the synchronization mechanism by cloning it and importing the project into one or the other eclipse environments.

Comment: I already have a SVN repo, which I used to checkout my project on my other eclipse env, but after that there are no options to do this sync.